# Print the last line in multiple text files at once as a list using python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have close to 1000 text files in a directory along with other files. I want to print the last line of each file as a list which also gives me corresponding file and last line of that file. Currently I have a program but this works for only one file at a time. I need to loop this through all the files and print the result as a list corresponding to each file.

```
    line = subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', filename])
```

All files that need to be read are named as coord_1.txt, coord_2.txt and so on. I need to write a program which reads the last line of every txt file and prints corresponding output. Each file either ends in 'P' or 'R' or 'N'.

Comment: the question being?

Comment: Show a reproducible example with sample input and output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I need to write a program which reads the last line of every txt file and prints corresponding output. Each file either ends in 'P' or 'R' or 'N'.

Comment: @Masklinn, I need to write a program which reads the last line of every txt file and prints corresponding output. Each file either ends in 'P' or 'R' or 'N'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text files are in a directory `textfiles` you can run the following piece of code just outside the directory setting `path` to `textfiles/`.

```
# |
# |____> text_files_directory/
# |____> pythonsource.py


from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import subprocess

path = "{your_path}"

# last_lines = [subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', path + filename]) for filename in [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)) and f.endswith('.txt')]]

filename_last_lines = [[(filename, subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', path + filename]))] for filename in [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)) and f.endswith('.txt')]]

# print(last_lines)
print(filename_last_lines)
```

This assumes that the text files extension is `.txt`.

Comment: How do I know which output corresponds to which flie? Is there any way to get corresponding outputs?

Comment: @accidental_coder Just modified my answer to account for that... Now it will return a list of tuples corresponding to (file_name, last_line).

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to get it as a list?

Comment: @accidental_coder The code returns a list of tuples with with all the file names and their corresponding last lines.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def get_last_line(file_path):
    with open('path/to/file','r') as f:
        return f.readlines()[-1]

last_lines = [get_last_line(join(mypath, f)) for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f)) and f.endswith('.txt')]
```

Comment: it says 'subprocess' is not defined

Comment: add `import subprocess` at the top of your file

Comment: It says subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['tail', '-1', 'coord_74.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: @accidental_coder updated my solution to more pythonic solution, please try.